# Toggle switch button not working in reactJs app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want a container with table that has one column "enabled" which can be toggled. I want to save the state of toggle in object I used to display the row (In the example below, I want to store it in `enable` attribute of student object). I have table and toggle button displaying properly. But the toggle button is not clickable/togglable and doesnt store the state. live code [here.](https://codepen.io/learnerReact/pen/YzKgpya)

Here is my code

```
class student {
  constructor(id, name, age,email,enable) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.email = email;
    this.enable = enable;
  }
}


const Switch = ({ isOn, handleToggle}) => {
    return (
    <>
      <input
        checked={isOn}
        onChange={handleToggle}
        className="react-switch-checkbox"
        id={`react-switch-new`}
        type="checkbox"
      />
      <label
        className="react-switch-label"
        htmlFor={`react-switch-new`}
      >
        <span className={`react-switch-button`} />
      </label>
    </>
  );
};




class Table extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
         students: [ new student(1, 'foo', 12, 'foo@gmail.com', true), 
                    new student(2, 'bar', 22, 'bar@gmail.com', false),
                    new student(3, 'foobar', 44, 'foo@gmail.com', true),
                    new student(4, 'foofoo',57,  'foofoo@gmail.com', false)
                    ]
      }
   }



   renderTableHeader() {
      let header = Object.keys(this.state.students[0])
      return header.map((key, index) => {
         return <th key={index}>{key.toUpperCase()}</th>
      })
   }

   renderTableData() {
      return this.state.students.map((student, index) => {
         const { id, name, age, email, enable } = student //destructuring
         //const [value, setValue] = useState(false);
         return (
            <tr key={id}>
               <td>{id}</td>
               <td>{name}</td>
               <td>{age}</td>
               <td>{email}</td>
             <td><Switch
        isOn={enable}
        handleToggle={() => student.enable=!enable}
      /></td>
            </tr>
         )
      })
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <h1 id='title'>React Dynamic Table</h1>
            <table id='students'>
               <tbody>
                  <tr>{this.renderTableHeader()}</tr>
                  {this.renderTableData()}
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </div>
      )
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Table />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Here is the screenshot of how page looks
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is, you cannot directly change the state like,

```
handleToggle={() => student.enable=!enable}
```

This will never change your state. To change your state you must use `setState`.

You should have a dedicated function to toggle your state,

```
handleToggle = (id) => {
   this.setState({
      students: this.state.students.map(std => {
        if(parseInt(std.id) === parseInt(id)){  //parse id to integer for safer side
          return {...std, enable: !std.enable}
        }else{
          return std;
        }
      })
   })
}
```

You should provide this function to your `Switch`. Also provide `id` for updation.

```
<Switch
    isOn={enable}
    id={id}   //provide id for updation
    handleToggle={this.handleToggle}   //provide function reference
/>
```

You need to make some changes to your `Switch`,

```
const Switch = ({ isOn, handleToggle, id}) => {   //take prop id
  return (
    <>
      <input
        checked={isOn}
        onChange={() => handleToggle(id)}   //call handleToggle using id
        className="react-switch-checkbox"
        id={`react-switch-new${id}`}        // Make it unique by adding id
        type="checkbox"
      />
      <label
        className="react-switch-label"
        htmlFor={`react-switch-new${id}`}   // Make it unique by adding id
      >
        <span className={`react-switch-button`} />
      </label>
    </>
  );
};
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qw1j4b)

Comment: what does `return {...std, enable: !std.enable}` mean?

Comment: Here we are updating state value based on `id`. So when `parseInt(std.id) === parseInt(id)` is `true`, we need to update that object with new value else we are returning the existing object. `{...std, enable: !std.enable}` means, [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the object (if `id` matches) and update the value of `enable` key.

Comment: When we say destructuring, `{...std}` is equivalent to `{"id":4,"name":"foofoo","age":57,"email":"foofoo@gmail.com","enable":false}` (just an example, actual object will be based on condition) and `{...std, enable: !std.enable}` means update the `enable` key (from `false` to `true` or vice-versa).

Comment: great solution. why do I need to `Make it unique by adding id` as you commented? I am not doing anything with that id anyway

Comment: Because in HTML itself `id` should be unique. As you are adding `Switch` in a `map` all the Switches gets the same `id`. If we have multiple same `id` then it is very difficult identify which switch is getting clicked and your toggle function will not get execute.

Comment: I agree id should be unique, but since I don't use id for any css or any other lookups, I left it as it is. But as a good practice, it should be made unique